# Redhat Enterprise Server 7.0 Black Screen after installing Team Viewer

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, teamviewer

I've stood up a RH server as a Windows Server hyper-v VM. Keep in mind I am relearning Linux after not using it for over 15 years. The server worked excellent until I installed Team Viewer for RHEL. Everything installed great but upon a reboot everything went wrong. After GRUB the version of RHEL displays the screen goes black and only a mouse pointer is displaying.

I'm new to Linux so please be easy on me. I can get to GRUB but nothing else seems to work and I'm not sure how to proceed. I'd rather not reinstall since it took me forever to learn how to set it up and install everything I needed.